# Python question: N is number of students and teachers, K is required beauty of chosen pair

Tags: python, algorithm

The question goes
There are N students standing in a row with indices from 1 to N, and N teachers standing in a row from 1 to N. It is given that the the beauty of one pair (student, teacher) is equal to the difference - in absolute value - between the index of the student and the index of the teacher. The beauty of all pairs is the sum of beauties of each pair. Your task is to find the total number of ways to make N pairs (student, teacher) such that the beauty of these pairs is equal to K.

Constraints:
1<=N<=50
0<=K<=N*N

Sample Input N=3 K=2
Output 2

Sample Input N=50 K=2
Output 49

Sample Input N=3 K=3
Output 0

```
import sys
def getCount(N,K):
  # my code
  l1=[]
  for i in range(N+1):
    l1.append(i)
  count=0
  for i in range(0,N):
    for j in range (i+1,N):
      if l1[i]-l1[j]==K or l1[j]-l1[i]==K:
        count+=1
  if count ==0:
    return 0
  else:
    return count+1
  # my code ends
def main():
  N=50
  K=2
  result=getCount(N,K)
  print(result)
if __name__=="__main__":
  main()
```

The issue is I got the test cases correct but when I Submit the code I got this

[This is test case which I passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymo72.jpg)

[This is the result after submitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeRmv.jpg)

Please help me, I have this coding exam next month

I redesigned my code to this:
will it work? for all testcases?

```
def getCount(N,K):
  # my code
  count=0
  if N==K:
    return 0
  for i in range(0,N-1):
    for j in range (i,N+1):
      if i-j==K or j-i==K:
        count+=1
  if count ==0:
    return 0
  else:
    return count
  # my code ends
def main():
  N=3
  K=3
  result=getCount(N,K)
  print(result)
if __name__=="__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: What are you doing differently between the first and the second image?

Comment: Why do you return count+1 ?

Comment: Also, why do you have your `l1` list containing N+1 elements?

Comment: @mkrieger1 its the same code but the test cases ran perfectly but the final testcases didnt

Comment: And why use `l1` at all where `l1[i]==i` for each `i` in the range?

Comment: @khelwood becos the answer was one less than the required output i didnt knew where the one less count went

Comment: The values of `l1` that you're checking are 0 to N-1. It looks like they are supposed to be 1 to N.

Comment: @khelwood so i must change i and j iteration

Comment: I suggest you lose `l1` and just iterate through the range you're supposed to check.

Comment: @khelwood I removed l1 and iterated with i and j with (0,N-1) and (i,N+1) respectively  also replaced count+1 in return with just return count and got the output but how can i know that the code will work in all testcases I dont have the hidden testcases.

Comment: If the score of each person is between 1 and N, why use the range (0,N-1) ? Including zero is contrary to the instructions.

Comment: @khelwood oh i miss read ur previous comment what ab j?